# How to Route Codeigniter with URI Segments there

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-3

how to route properly url with segments in codeigniter.
this is my url .

```
https://www.test.com/region/india/about/people/gaurav-Singh/1
```

this is in my route

```
$route['region/india/about/people/(:any)/(:any)']  = "region/india/memberview/$1/$2";
```

this is my controller

```
public function memberview()
{
 $teamid = $this->uri->segment(5);      
 $data['view'] = 'region/india/team-member-view.php';
 $this->load->model('region/India_model');
 $data['team'] = $this->India_model->tmview($teamid);
 $this->load->view('region/layout', $data);
}
```

this is my model

```
public function tmview($teamid){

        $this->db->query("select * from ojiteam");
        $this->db->where('id',$teamid);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();

    }
```

in my view i am showing data with

```
<?php echo $team['tmname'];?>
```

but its not working, it is showing 500 error.

help me with this issue. i have searched and went through codeigniter but not able to solve this.

Comment: it's a typo: it should be `$this->uri->segment(6);`

Comment: no its not working,, its returning 500 error.

Comment: 500 error says something is wrong serverside, does the query return something? read also: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI

Comment: maybe the column 'id' is actually 'ID' ? also check `echo $this->db->last_query();`and see if the query works or fails in your PhpMyAdmin (or similar)

Comment: @Vickel - SELECT `NAME`, `VALUE` FROM `TBLOPTIONS` WHERE `AUTOLOAD` = 1   

this is the response i got when i queried in view

Comment: when i comment out //model code ,, view getting loaded else it shows 500 error

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the environment you are working on ([see docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/environments.html)) you can debug to figure out what is causing this 500 error. Usually this means somehting is wrong with your code, you will have to debug to find out what file and line this error is generated from.

To use numbers in your routing you should do (:num), this way only numbers are allowed on that part of your routing ([see docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)).

On the controller part, you can pass variables to your controller from your routing options, so;

```
$route['region/india/about/people/(:any)/(:any)']  = "region/india/memberview/$1/$2";

public function memberview( $area, $teamid )
{
      // Your coding
      // $area now is; gaurav-Singh
      // $teamid now is; 1
}
```

This way you don't have to worry about which part of the URL you need to use because it's all set.